# HP MSA1500 - getting past the 2TB limit?

Tags: windows-server-2003, storage, storage-area-network, hp-modular-smart-array

I currently have (7) 300GB drives in the MSA1500.  This is configured with RAID 5 which results in a 1.8TB drive, about 1.6TB formatted. I still have 7 more empty slots in the enclosure that I would like to fill but it seems pretty fruitless.  If the LUN limitation of the MSA is 2TB then I probably can only add 1 more 300GB drive. I need to be able to create a continuous logical drive that maintains millions of scanned images.  Is there anyway I can get past this 2TB limitation?

Thank you,
Azee

Comment: Definitely time to upgrade...

Answer (score 3):

Create 2 LUNs of 7 drives each. Use the raid abilities of your OS to stripe a volume across both arrays.

Or better yet, pick a ZFS capable OS and let ZFS handle the RAID for you.

Comment: Or use a clusterfs like gluster or ceph.

Comment: I have not been able to find any documentation that clearly outlines this. Please confirm: create 2 logical RAID 5 drives each having 7 drives. Using Disk Management within W2K3 SP2, do I simply create a new volume by adding the 2 drives? Do these have to be GPT? Are there steps I am missing? You see, I'm starting to get fuzzy here... any help or links would be appreciated!

Comment: They do not have to be GPT but they do need to be dynamic. Complete instructions here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323433